# Meteor FindOne Result

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am having problems accessing the fields of a Meteor Collections findOne Result in javascript.  I am well aware that you can use a template to print each field but I need them in javascript for my functions before rendering the interior of the if.  Please see below.

javascript:

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");


Template.gameLobby.notInGame = function() {
    var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("playerId"));        
    alert(player.gameId);
    if (Session.equals("lobbyGame", player.gameId)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


Template.gameLobby.showGamePlayers = function (){
    var id = Session.get("lobbyGame")
    return Players.find({gameId: id});
}
```

HTML:

```
<template name="gameLobby">
  {{#each showGamePlayers}}
      {{> playerName}}
  {{/each}}
  {{#if notInGame}}
       <input class="join" value="Join Game">
  {{else}}
       Waiting for players
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

2 Problems I am having.

1. notInGame always returns true because alert(player.gameId) prints undefined so I assume this is not how you reference fields from a FindOne() result.
2. Every time i try and add the template name="playerName" the page will not load even if i only put static html in the template.  I specifically named this playerName because i already have a player template that acts on the same object different.  Just for kicks i changed it to > player and that also fails.

Comment: Maybe you need `Players.findOne({_id: Session.get('playerId')})` because usually a query selector in mongodb is an object.

Comment: If you check for bad/undefined session data instead of using it immediately in a query, what happens?

Comment: Hi Paul. 1.  No Players.findOne({_id: Session.get('playerId)}); did not make a difference.  I was using the simpler syntax reserved for the _id field above.

Comment: 2. if you check a session for something = underfined it always returns true.

Comment: If you want to simplify the logic of making games for different players, you may want to check out https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-partitioner. You may also want to see https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor, which uses that to conduct human subject experiments studying groups of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help I have found the solution.  No player in the system had a gameId on there object thus the field rightfully does not exist according to MongoDB once I ran this `Players.Insert({name: "fakePlayer", gameId:"fakeId"});` everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Meteor MongoDB's automatic _id assignment as the value in your **playerId** session?

If so, you should use `player._id` in retrieving that value :

```
Template.gameLobby.notInGame = function() {
    var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("playerId"));        
    alert(player._id);
    if (Session.equals("lobbyGame", player._id)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am doing.  Session.get("playerId") is the player._id.  gameId is a field on the object.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add a .fetch() after findOne(). Otherwise you get the cursor back and not the real object that you want.

Comment: Can you add some code showing how you would use this? It would be much more helpful to the OP and future visitors to SO.

Comment: `findOne` returns a document, not a cursor, so no need (one can't!) to use `fetch` as mentioned.